# How to get the value of the item source in datatrigger in a combobox?

Tags: c#, wpf, datatrigger

I have a combobox which itemsource is a collection of type MyTpye. My type is something like that:

```
Class MyClass
{
    long ID;
    string Description;
    decimal Value;
}
```

For DisplayMemberPath I am using the Value property. The problema is that is a decimal, not decimal?, so in the case that ID is 0 then the value is 0 too. I would like to display in this case 0.

So I am trying to use a datatrigger in this way:

```
<ComboBox Name="myComboBox"
          DisplayMemberPath="Value"
          ItemsSource="{Biniding MyCollection}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=MySelectedItem}">
    <ComboBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ???, path=ID}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Style>
</ComboBox>
```

The problem is that in the binding of the datatrigger, I don't know how to get the item of the collection that is the sorce of the item of the combobox, and from this item, the ID property.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the `DisplayMemberPath` and use an `ItemTemplate` to display either the value of the `Value` property or something else:

```
<ComboBox Name="myComboBox"
          ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=MySelectedItem}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Value}" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value}" Value="0">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="..." />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

In the above example, "..." will be displayed instead of "0" for any item with a `Value` of `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `SelectedItem.ID` in your `DataTrigger` binding path.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.ID}" Value="0">
```

Or, you can instead add another property to your `MyClass` of type `decimal?` and use that for DisplayMemberPath.

```
public decimal? DisplayValue { get => ID == 0 ? default(decimal?) : Value; }
```